# Interface Builder "locking" object to screen edges

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

I've read some tutorials on using AutoLayout but I just can't seem to figure out how to achieve something that I feel should be incredibly simple. I'm designing an application for both 3.5 and 4 inch iPhone/iPod Touch screens. It's a simple tab bar application with a UITableView filling up the entirety of each tab, like so:

[image: Interface Builder]

I would like for the UITableView to lock to the edges of the screen, regardless of whether the screen is 3.5 or 4 inches. What I currently have works fine on 4-inch screens, but on 3.5 the UITableView extends beyond the width of the screen.

I've tried reading some AutoLayout tutorials as well as fiddling with Interface Builder constraints, but without success. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: For what you're doing, you might as well just disable Auto Layout and set the autoresizing mask (springs and struts) to pin the table view to all 4 edges, and allow it to be flexible width & height. But if you're interested in using Auto Layout, I personally recommend creating your constraints in code instead of Interface Builder because IB can be a pain to work with and in many cases what you see isn't what you get. I have a nice open source API that makes it much easier, and there's a sample project too you can play with: https://github.com/smileyborg/UIView-AutoLayout

Comment: (Using the UIView+AutoLayout API, you just need one line: `[tableView autoPinEdgesToSuperviewEdgesWithInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero];`) It's that easy!

Comment: What constraints do you have set now? You can post those so we can help you understand where you went wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to attach the `UITableView` to all edges of the parent `UIView`, and then the `UITableView` will expand or shrink to fill the `UIView` on the device. This will make it appear to be the proper size on all iDevices, including iPad. As pictured in the screenshot below, you can just tap all the dashed red guides, making sure the margins are set to 0 (touch the sides):

[image: AutoLayout via IB for a UITableView touching all sides of the parent view]

You could also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + drag left, drag right, drag up, and drag down on the `UITableView` choosing "Leading Space to Container", "Trailing Space to Container," "Top Space to Top Layout Guide", and "Bottom Space to Bottom Layout" respectively.

Alternatively,  you could use the [Visual Format Language (VFL)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html) (code for a `UIViewController` below assumes your `UITableView` is an auto-`@synthesized` `@property` named `tableView`):

```
/* Turn off springs/structs */
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

/* Leading and trailing constraints */
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_tableView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];
/* Top and bottom constraints */
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_tableView]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_tableView)]];
```

...or if you *really* like to be explicit (and like typing):

```
/* Leading constaint (could use NSLayoutAttributeLeft here as well) */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1 constant:0]];
/* Trailing constraint (could use NSLayoutAttributeRight here as well) */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1 constant:0]];
/* Top constraint */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1 constant:0]];
/* Bottom constraint */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0]];
```

The important thing with all of this is that the `UITableView` is a child of the `view` of the `UIViewController` (it most likely is). `view` will fill the screen as expected by default, and with all of the methods above, you're asking the layout to hold tight against the edges of that maximized view.

Answer (score 1):

NSLayoutConstraints is ridiculous overkill for this IMHO. 
Just turn it off and do this

```
self.tableview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: FYI I'm pretty sure iOS will translate this autoresizing mask into layout constraints behind the scenes anyway, so Jef's answer is actually a very simple way to take advantage of layout constraints.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that..  Except on earlier systems pre iOs7 it'll work as expected rather than spit the dummy and throw an 'wtf is NSLayoutConstraint' type exception :)

Comment: Right. If you're interested you can check into UIView's translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property.